# Searching a contact without country code in mat input (angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, input, angular-material, mat-input

I am working on `matinput` in angular templates. I am using it for searching puposes inside a list. In list we have different customers with contact i.e. (country code)(phone-number) +92 3011111111. When I search for +92 301... It works fine. But when I replace `+92` with `0` (as per number format in our region) It returns me with no contact. Is there any way to replace `+92` or any other country code with `0`. Thanks in advance. Lemme know if more clarification is needed. (vote question up if its clear and fine so i can ask more questions when needed)

*Current angular version working with: 9*

Comment: Can you include code it'll be easier to recommend an approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by replacing +92 with 0 while searching as it will check for both +92 when + is in the search and Will search with 0 when there is no + character in search